# Raspberry pi, run Python script on startup, cron has failed, /etc/profile has failed, .config/autostart has failed, other methods?

Tags: python, authentication, cron, raspberry-pi3, autostart

Excuse me, I'm trying to get a python script I have written to autostart on a raspberry pi. I've tried several methods but they've all failed.

I have tried some methods using cron's "@reboot" feature, but these seem to make my script run too early in the boot sequence, early enough that the libraries it needs haven't loaded yet and other crucial functions of the pi that it has to make use of haven't yet started. For example I had this error occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program_name.py", line 688, in <module>
    fig=plt.figure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 435, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 89, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1813, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Which is odd for a start because I'm using pygame not tkinter. And it is not an error that has ever occured when I've just run my program using "python program_name.py" from the terminal, so it is clearly a problem with trying to run the script at the wrong moment rather than a problem in the script. Also when this happened the program tried to run for a moment before crashing with this error, but the mouse was very slow and juddery when I tried to move it around on the screen and the window which is usually a full screen one with the relevant bits of the GUI in the middle and black space (a kind of "actual size however big the screen might be" display ) around it had been distorted to become a kind of "fill the screen even if this wrecks you aspect ratio" display.

I have also tried using /etc/profile using /etc/xdg/autostart/myprogram.desktop and using various methods with init.d but all of these seem to do nothing, the pi logs in normally and my python program doesn't start.

Is there anyway to get the python program to run automatically just after the pi has logged itself in, so you would effectively see the pi startup as normal, and the normal desktop start to load but then a split second later the script would begin and (as it is a pygame based python GUI) the desktop would then be covered over by it.

Thanks

Comment: I've managed to make a launcher.sh script which successfully runs my python script regardless of which folder the .sh script is executed from.

Comment: I've also done a test trying to run my program from within the ctrl+alt+f1 environment, this leads to the same type of failure as if I try to run @reboot using cron. I have no problems when my python code is run from the normal terminal within the GUI, s I'm guessing that what I need for my program to be able to autorun is a way to make it not try to auto-execute until the Rasberry pi has booted far enough that the X window GUI desktop enviornment has loaded. thanks